# code first with abstract class, the fk couldn't generated

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, abstract-class

please look at the code below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (myContext context = new myContext())
        {
            Team t = new Team();
            t.id = 1;
            t.Name = "asd";
            context.teamSet.Add(t);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Player : Base
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual Team team { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("team")]
    public int teamId { get; set; }
}

public class Team : Base
{
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FootballPlayer : Player
{
    public double Speed { get; set; }
}

public class BasketballPlayer : Player
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
}

public class myContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> playerSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> teamSet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BaseConfiguration()).Add(new PlayerConfiguration()).Add(new TeamConfiguration()).Add(new FootballConfiguration()).Add(new BasketballConfiguration());           
    }
}

public class BaseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Base>
{
    public BaseConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(k => k.id);
        Property(p => p.id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}

public class PlayerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
{ 
    public PlayerConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p=>{
            p.MapInheritedProperties();
        p.ToTable("Player");
        });
    }
}

public class TeamConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
{
    public TeamConfiguration()
    {
        Map(p =>
        {
            p.MapInheritedProperties();
            p.ToTable("Team");
        });
    }
}

public class FootballConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FootballPlayer>
{
    public FootballConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("FootballPlayer");
    }
}

public class BasketballConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<BasketballPlayer>
{
    public BasketballConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("BasketballPlayer");
    }
}
```

My Player class and Team Class are derived from Based Class, and FootballPlayer and BasketballPlayer are derived from Player. But in the generated database, Player table doesn't contain a FK teamId, it is only a common property. Furthermore, the FootballPlayer and BasketballPlayer tables don't contains the properties which derived from Player class. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What inheritance mapping are you trying to achieve? At the moment you have TPC between `Base` and `Player` and TPT between `Player` and its derived types. If you want to have inherited properties in those derived types you must use TPC as well but in such case there should be no `Player` table in your database. To use TPC for player you must use `MapInheritedProperties` in their mapping configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've got the peroperties which in Player table. But could you tell me how to make 'teamId' in 'Player' table as a FK? Thanks!

Comment: furthermore, player and team are tpc and footballplayer and basketballplayer are tpt

Comment: In such case you cannot have derived columns in `FootballPlayer` and `BasketballPlayer` tables.